# How to change the scrollbar styles in Angular Material select?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

We need help in changing the scrollbar in the Select component from Angular Material.

The following demo was implemented.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxbvndrpogl?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.ts

[image: Mat-Select]

However, I need help in changing the width and style of the scrollbar.

[Example](https://rd-dev-ukraine.github.io/angular-io-slimscroll)

Answer (score 73):

Usually the way to customize the scroll is:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #b30000; 
}
```

You cannot directly inspect the scroll from the dev tools, however you can see the styling of it if you inspect the div that has the `overflow` property with the `scroll;` value in it.

Comment: it is working for chrome, but not working for Firefox and Edge since I upgrade to angular + material 6. any ideas ? thank you

Comment: Because it is for chrome. -_- Hope you noticed the `-webkit-` prefix. ^_^

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is only working when I write this in root css file. It is not working when written in component css file. I can see the css in dev tool. Any idea?

Comment: Perfect. Someone hand this guy a medal.

Comment: @ChandreshMishra paste the code at the end of component css file and it will work.

Comment: @Leepians I don't even work on that project anymmore. lol

Answer (score 19):

to change the color and width it worked for me -

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: grey;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #707070;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me and I use "display:none"  inside 'webkit-scrollbar' to hide scroll bar completely. So scroll bar not visible anymore and scroll work perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

I hope I am not late, I had a similar problem with the native scroll bar.

The way I would solve this problem is to use [Simple bar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar)  library then I would made directive and only wrap

```
 <mat-select placeholder="State">
    <div appSimpleBar>
       <mat-option>None</mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
```

This will do the trick of hiding native scroll bar

Comment: Sorry to ask, but do you have a demo somewhere ? I could not make it work in Angular.

Comment: here is the sample  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2czkp but sometimes it is working on stackblitz sometimes not. But I am using it on multiple projects and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Because, when you using Angular one common attribute will be rendered in DOM like ng-content which will over write your class properties written in CSS, so try this code this will eliminate native Angular styles to use in application.

Go to the Component,

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
```

Then

```
@Component({
.....
.....
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then your styles will taken by browser.

Answer (score 1):

For me above methods not working. I used the following css styles

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-panel::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
     background-color:   rgb(233, 245, 233)
}

::ng-deep .mat-select-panel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(233, 245, 233) !important; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```