# Angular Material Styling

Tags: css, angular-material, angular6

I can seem to style the scrollbar on the mat-option field with css. I want to make the scrollbar a different size and color. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

I tried doing this below but it didn't work.

[How to change the scrollbar styles in Angular Material select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610619/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-styles-in-angular-material-select)

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts | async" [value]="product">
      {{ product.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Does anyone have anything? I looked on Angular Materials site and found nothing pertaining styling https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#customizing-the-trigger-label

Answer (score 1):

To apply style to the autocomplete panel, you simply add a class to the autocomplete element. See the docs on the 'class' @Input: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocomplete.

For example:

```
<mat-autocomplete class="custom-scroll" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
```

And then in your **global** scss:

```
.custom-scroll.mat-autocomplete-panel {

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to change it all for scroll bars in your Angular project:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 6px !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
border-radius: 4px !important;
background-color: #EFEFEF!important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 4px !important;
background-color: #DCB064 !important;
}
```